# Destroy-like functionality using a custom controller method in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, controller, destroy

I have a resource called `patient_admissions` that has all the RESTful routes. It is nested under another resource called `patients`. I want to add another method to my `patient_admissions` controller called `discharge` that updates a field in the model called `:discharge_date` (with `Date.now`) and saves that value in the table.

I would like this to work like the `destroy` method, in that if I have a bunch of `patient_admission` objects listed in a table in my `index` view, I could just click on the `Discharge` link and a confirmation box would appear, I would click 'ok' and then the value would be updated without having to first go to another view and deal with forms.

How can I do this without resorting to something like javascript? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rails guide on Routing, there's a section on [adding additional restful actions:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

The example there would translate to something like:

```
resources :patient_admissions do
  member do
    put 'discharge'
  end
end
```

This will recognize `/patient_admissions/1/discharge` with PUT, and route to the discharge action of `PatientAdmissionsController`.

This will at least allow you to get the routing set up for the action.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by using the `link_to` or `button_to` helpers in conjunction with a custom member route for your controller. Here is an example:

```
#routes.rb
resources :patient_adminssions do
  put :discharge, :on => :member
end
```

Notice that I used PUT to add the custom route because the record will not be deleted, just modified. So according to the REST standards, I think put is the most appropriate.

```
# in your view
<%= button_to "Discharge", discharge_patient_admission_path(@patient_admission), :method => :put,
             :confirm => "Are you sure you want to discharge this patient?" %>
```

This will create a button in a hidden form that when clicked will display the confirmation message and if it is confirmed then it will send a request to your controller action where you can set the appropriate discharge date like you suggested.